# Elasticsearch: Set Java version without using JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In Windows environments, is there a way to indicate ElasticSearch (installed as a service) the Java location to be used without using the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable?

In order to deliver ElasticSearch to our customers we would like to deliver it with a private JRE 8, so we need to point to that specific version. The easiest way is to use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. However, we would like to avoid interfering with other applications that may use that variable.

Comment: You could set the JAVA_HOME variable just in the script that launches elsasticsearch. That wouldn't affect other applications.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I'm not sure which is the script that launches ElasticSearch. By installing it with the MSI I get some batch files under `C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\6.2.4\bin`. The `elasticsearch-env.bat` seems to be a candidate. However, changing there the Java location does not affect the service. I'm not sure how ElasticSearch service uses that batch file (maybe after restart during initialization?).

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is indeed the preferred way to indicate which Java to use to the environment that wishes to use it, hence the "environment" in the "variable". How else would Elastic Search go about it? What if you have 25 different Java installations in different places? It rightfully shouldn't apply any heuristics but fail without `JAVA_HOME` telling it which Java to  use. I agree with @ernest_k -- find an appropriate place to set the variable, most operating systems allow a process to use its own set of environment variables, without affecting anything else, that's sort of the purpose of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own issue by using a ZIP version of Elasticsearch (instead of the *.msi). The idea is to set the `JAVA_HOME` to the private JRE/JDK in the same installing `CMD` process and then call:

- `\bin\elasticsearch-service.bat install`
- `\bin\elasticserach-service.bat start`

Previously, the `elasticsearch-service.bat` must be modified to add the option `--Jvm "%JAVA_HOME%%JVM_DLL%"` instead of `--Jvm "%%JAVA_HOME%%%JVM_DLL%"`